# Running JSP page in Tomcat Server?

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I'm new to JSP. I'm  trying to run JSP page in TOMCAT server.

Following are  the steps I used.

1). Created the following JSP page for disaplying current date.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" import="java.util.*" %>

<html>
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div align="center">
<center>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing
="0" width="460" bgcolor="#EEFFCA">

<tr>
<td width="100%"><font size="6" color
="#008000">&nbsp;Date Example</font></td>    
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%"><b>&nbsp;Current Date
and time is:&nbsp; <font color="#FF0000">    
<%= new java.util.Date() %>
</font></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

2) Save it with the name Date.jsp in webapps(webapps/JSPSample/date.jsp) in the tomcat

3) I also created WEB-INF folder inside JSPSample folder.Inside WEB_INF folder I place web.xml with following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application   2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
<display-name>JSP test client</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>JSP Sample</servlet-name>
<display-name>JSP Sample</display-name>
<description>no description</description>
<jsp-file>/date.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

</web-app>
```

4) The folder structure looks like

```
 webapps
          --JSPSample
                   ----WEB-INF--web.xml
                   ----date.jsp
```

5) Later, opened any internet browser and typed the following URL

```
   http://localhost:8080/JSPSample/date.jsp
```

Following errors are showing while trying to run the JSP file

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:156)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.hp.sips.basic.container.impl.servlet.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:67)

root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:620)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:144)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.hp.sips.basic.container.impl.servlet.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:67)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.UIDesign_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:618)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:144)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.hp.sips.basic.container.impl.servlet.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:67)
```

When refreshing the page bellow error is also showing

```
     exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/CategorizedProblem;
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:275)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.hp.sips.basic.container.impl.servlet.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:67)

root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/CategorizedProblem;
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$2.acceptResult(JDTCompiler.java:370)
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:429)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    com.hp.sips.basic.container.impl.servlet.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:67)
```

Comment: You don't have to define jsp files in web.xml

Comment: yes i removed that..but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just downloaded [Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi), created files `/webapps/JSPSample/date.jsp` and `/webapps/JSPSample/WEB-INF/web.xml` with your content and it just worked.

Which means that the problem is with your environment (the way Tomcat is installed, operating system, IDE), and not with Tomcat.

Comment: i didnt get you,will you plase describe it more about "Which means that your environment is screwed up in same very special Eclipse-related way."

Comment: @chinchu: You should have no a single JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and you should also not have manually changed project's build path in any way. If that isn't the problem or does not solve it, then your Eclipse environment is definitely screwed up. Reinstall Eclipse and do not do things of which you do not really understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I found that having jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar in the WEB-INF/lib causes the problem.

Comment: This resolved my issue. But how this jar got there? I don't have this jar in pom.xml